# How to write the docker script such that sudo works in Docker user?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, docker, sudo

I've ran an empty Docker container with Ubuntu and created a `sudo` user as such:

```
user@server$ docker run -it ubuntu bash

root@6da1c5bc7f93:/# apt-get update
root@6da1c5bc7f93:/# apt-get -y install sudo

root@6da1c5bc7f93:/# useradd -m -p mosesdocker -s /bin/bash ubiwan
root@6da1c5bc7f93:/# usermod -aG sudo ubiwan  # add user to sudo list
root@6da1c5bc7f93:/# su - ubiwan  # login to the ubiwan user
```

And when I logged in as `ubiwan`, the password doesn't seem to be `mosesdocker` as specified by `useradd -m -p mosesdocker -s /bin/bash ubiwan`. I've typed the correct password but I get:

```
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.

ubiwan@6da1c5bc7f93:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for ubiwan: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for ubiwan: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for ubiwan: 
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

Why is that so?

**Is it possible to use `sudo` in Docker? What is the "suggested" to perform `sudo` actions in Docker?**

**How to write the docker script such that sudo works in Docker user?**

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the password for the user as root using passwd.

First of all type exit if you are logged in as ubiwan. 
Then as root type:

```
passwd ubiwan
```

Give a password for this user.
Then you can use sudo as the ubiwan user with this password

Comment: Ah but the password needs to be set non-interactively in the docker script.

Comment: RUN echo "user ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/user && \
    chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/user

maybe you need something like above? taken from http://gbraad.nl/blog/non-root-user-inside-a-docker-container.html

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why is `-p` not taking effect on `useradd`?